# Pip freeze requirements.txt is not working

Tags: python, pycharm

This are my imports:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
from collections import defaultdict
import re
```

But my requirements.txt only returns:

```
pandas~=1.2.0
matplotlib~=3.3.3
```

Comment: All the other packages are part of the standard library and don't need to be installed...

Answer (score 0):

As the comment suggested you are misunderstanding [the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/index.html) and external library.

For example the **re** package is a part of the [python standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

A good way to ensure that all of your external libraries is freeze is to run **pip list**, it will show all the package you have installed.